# Akka.NET DI on Windows Services & Best Practices

Tags: dependency-injection, windows-services, ninject, akka.net

I am trying to migrate parts of a Windows Service into the AKKA.net actor model however when it comes to DI for the actors (they have some dependencies such as data access layer, etc.) I'm having a bit of a problem because I don't fully understand how to wire up the DependencyResolver in the service. If that was a web application then it would be DependencyResolver of the HttpConfiguraiton however in this case I currently have the standard kernel to do the bootstrapping and get the top level interface implementacion to start the Windows Service.

I would have then two questions:

- What's the way to configure DI for actors in windows services?
- What's the best way to get the system actor from within another class?

I have been reading here: http://getakka.net/docs/Dependency%20injection#ninject

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using Akka.NET in a windows service (with topshelf and autofac but this approach should work for any service runner and IoC framework). I start up the top level actor in the startup method of the service like so:

```
_scope.Resolve<ActorSystem>().ActorOf<MyTopLevelActor>().Tell(new StartMySystemMessage());
```

From there I create child actors with either

```
var actorWithoutDependencies = Context.ActorOf<ChildActorType>();
```

where the actor type has a default constructor, or

```
var actorWithDependencies = Context.ActorOfDI<ChildActorType>();
```

where the child actor type has dependencies.

The ActorOfDI calls are extension methods which I use to wrap the ActorSystem.DI() and IActorContext.DI() methods in akka.net as follows:

```
    public static IActorRef ActorOfDI<T>(this ActorSystem actorSystem, string name = null) where T : ActorBase
    {
        return actorSystem.ActorOf(actorSystem.DI().Props<T>(), name);
    }

    public static IActorRef ActorOfDI<T>(this IActorContext actorContext, string name = null) where T : ActorBase
    {
        return actorContext.ActorOf(actorContext.DI().Props<T>(), name);
    }
```

In terms of IoC configuration for the actors, I'm registering all actor types in the assemblies containing the actors (using Autofac) as follows:

```
containerBuilder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(SomeActorType).Assembly).Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith("Actor"));
```

and to register the actor system itself I'm doing this:

```
containerBuilder.Register(c =>
{
    var system = ActorSystem.Create("MyActorSystem");
    // ReSharper disable once ObjectCreationAsStatement
    new AutoFacDependencyResolver(lazyContainer.Value, system);
    return system;
}).As<ActorSystem>().SingleInstance();
```

where lazyContainer is a:

```
Lazy<IContainer> // this is an autofac type
```

and the constructor delegate calls

```
containerBuilder.Build() // this is an autofac call
```

To get the actor system from within another dependency injected class you can then just pass an ActorSystem into the constructor for the class. I'm not sure about getting a reference to the system actor in my application code - I haven't needed to do that myself.

Comment: Hi Steve, many thanks for this. I got that working using your tips and extension methods. I'm using Ninject at the moment but the solution is very similar. My use case though would be to have a dependency of the system actor (IActorRefFactory) that I inject to my first non actor class that will be using it. Then from there I need to get the "top level actor" which will I pass it and get the first actor and pass my "start message". From that actor I can access the context then and I can resolve the DIActors using your extension method. Does it make sense? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi Carlos, great, I'm glad that helped. Yes your scenario makes sense to me - I'm injecting a concrete ActorSystem at the top level as it makes things slightly simpler in my scenario but injecting an IActorRefFactory can work too.

Answer (score 0):

I would configure my DI immediately after starting up the actor system for the process. This is the best I can offer as I've not used Akka within the context of a windows service yet.

If you need other classes to be able to access the actor system in order to be able to create Toplevel actors, you could register the actorsystem instance itself as `IActorRefFactory` which gives you access to the `ActorOf()` and `ActorSelection()` methods.  Obviously as a single instance here, not transient lifespan.

If you mean that you want to resolve the *system actor* rather than the actorsystem, ie `/system` actor in other classes, I'm not sure this is possible.  My limited understanding of DI in Akka.net is that you can't register and resolve live actors, as this doesn't work with respect to actor lifecycles, you can only register the dependencies required to startup new actors.  As a result of this, I tend to fire up my toplevel actors manually aroudn the time that I register my container, and all their children via DI.

If you have isolated classes which aren't actors and need to have an access point into the actorsystem, I'd suggest registering `IActorRefFactory` as above and creating those actors as needed.

This is a bit of a square-peg-round-hole issue I've been having in my own project, so I'd welcome any other answers that suggest a better way.